# Slider Revolution for React

Tags: wordpress, animation, react

I see Slider Revolution is a Wordpress plugin, makes nice animation, slider effect i.e. in hero in a Wordpress site. Is it any simiular solution for a React website?

https://www.sliderrevolution.com

I have seen a 2 years old repo in NPMJS, is it any newer similar solution?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-revolution

I bought Zircona template in React: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/zircona-it-solutions-technology-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/26902789